# How a JSON object with Java?

Tags: java, json

I need to create the following JsonObject using JAVA:

```
{
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest"],
    "Operations": [{
        "method": "DELETE",
        "path": "/Users/955ec8cd2bfc4af8998f6f5655d3bde8?forceDelete=true"
    }, {
        "method": "DELETE",
        "path": "/Users/97c46f642a084570a9c2fe959f8d14b3?forceDelete=true"
    }, {
        "method": "DELETE",
        "path": "/Users/cce146e8092a4458b1297a9ebb82e980?forceDelete=true"
    }]
}
```

I am unable to create the exact JsonObject.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? add that code please

Comment: I improved wording and formatting of your question, but I agree with the comments: A) this is most likely duplicate, and more importantly B) when you have "not working" code, then read [mcve] and add that code + error description to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create java POJO class corresponding to your json object.

```
class TestPojo{
private List<String> schemas;
...
...
// and Getter & Setters
}
```

Then Use Gson Class

```
TestPojo obj=new TestPojo(); //fill obj with required values
Gson gson=new Gson();
String jsonString= gson.toJson(obj); // jsonString will have JSON of class TestPojo
```

Comment: What if I dont want to use Gson Class.

Comment: @SurbhiMittal You have to use some other API like- Jackson or something else..